# cannot upgrade Kubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu

I have `Kubuntu 14.10` with `Linux desktop001 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` kernel and when I issue command for system upgrade: `clear && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove`, the updare stops at: `100% [Waiting for headers]` and after some time I get warnings and error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  0  Requested Range Not Satisfiable [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  0  Requested Range Not Satisfiable [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is first time I cannot upgrade system, why?!

Comment: The PPA doesn't support 14.10. As for the Ubuntu mirror, try another mirror, perhaps another local to your country, or one in another country.

Comment: @muru, what is PPA?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them. I'm referring to the lines with `inameiname/stable` in them, which are from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~inameiname/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `sources.list` file as the superuser.

```
sudo kate /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment out the following line:

```
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe restricted multiverse main #Added by software-properties
```

It worked for me.

URL : https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58645-Error-when-updating.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The OP may not know how to comment out a line. What about the other references to Saucy or the ppa?

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with your internet, you might also try making a new sources.list using the website http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/